# Override ul default disc icon with details icon

Tags: html, css

I have a an unordered list. I would like to use `<details>` to optionally display a sublist for one of the bullets:

```html
<ul>
  <li><details>
    <summary>details bullet</summary>
    <ul>
      <li>detail 1</li>
      <li>detail 2</li>
    </ul>
  </details></li>

  <li>content 2
    <ul>
      <li>detail 2</li>
      <li>detail 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works, but creates two bullet icons for "details bullet": the disc from `<li>` and the triangle from `<details>`, e.g., `* > details bullet`.

**I want the triangle to replace the disc on "details bullet" so that there is only one bullet icon, e.g., `> details bullet`.**

---

My Unhelpful Research:

From reading [MDN's `<ul>` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), I see I am not allowed to make `<details>` a top-level element of `<ul>` (i.e., I must wrap it as `<li><details>...</li>`), and even when I tried doing that it did not work as desired.

From reading [MDN's list-style-type page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type), I see that the details triangle is not one of the options.

I tried combinations of setting

```css
ol {
  list-style: inside|outside;
}
details > summary {
  list-style: inside|outside;
}
```

but they did not have the desired effect (some combinations removed the second bullet icon, some replaced it with a second disc, but none moved the triangle in place of the first disc).

How can I replace the disc icon with the triangle icon for a bullet point with details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate this using a negative `text-indent` and remove the default bullet

```css
.detail {
  list-style: none;
}

.detail details {
  text-indent: -16px;
}

.detail details > ul {
  margin-left:16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="detail">
    <details>
      <summary>details bullet</summary>
      <ul>
        <li>detail 1</li>
        <li>detail 2</li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </li>

  <li>content 2
    <ul>
      <li>detail 2</li>
      <li>detail 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention if you could add classes to the HTML, so I thought it would be a neat exercise to try without touching the HTML. Oddly, "empty bullets" (or circle bullets) are not the same size when added via pseudo class in comparison to list-style.

```css
/* Circle bullet */
li ul:first-of-type li:first-child::marker,
li ul:first-of-type li::marker{
    content: "○   ";
    font-size: 80%;
}
/* Remove bullet */
ul:first-of-type li:first-child::marker {content: "";}
/* Indent details */
li details {
    margin: 0 0 0 -18px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><details>
    <summary>details bullet</summary>
    <ul>
      <li>detail 1</li>
      <li>detail 2</li>
    </ul>
  </details></li>

  <li>content 2
    <ul>
      <li>detail 2</li>
      <li>detail 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```